# org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid XML

Tags: java, mage

I am trying to add a image to a product in magento through magja and I get the invalid xml error `
Below is the code which takes care of the image insertion ..
Can any one tell me, Why I am getting this error.

byte[] data = MagjaFileUtils.getBytesFromFileURL("http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/2178/2178004_sd.jpg");

```
        Media image = new Media();
        image.setName("google");
        image.setMime("image/jpeg");
        image.setData(data);

        Set<ProductMedia.Type> types = ImmutableSet.of(ProductMedia.Type.IMAGE, ProductMedia.Type.SMALL_IMAGE);

        ProductMedia media = new ProductMedia();
        media.setExclude(false);
        media.setImage(image);
        media.setLabel("Image for Product");
        media.setPosition(1);
        media.setTypes(types);
        media.setProduct(product);
      product.addMedia(media);`
```

> 2016-01-22 11:48:51 ERROR ProductMediaRemoteServiceImpl:528 - 
>   org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Invalid XML
>       at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
>       at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:555)
>       at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:531)
>       at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.call(MagentoSoapClient.java:253)
>       at com.google.code.magja.soap.MagentoSoapClient.callArgs(MagentoSoapClient.java:213)
>       at com.google.code.magja.service.product.ProductMediaRemoteServiceImpl.create(ProductMediaRemoteServiceImpl.java:213)
>       at com.niveus.integrator.test.MagentoProductClient.generateProduct(MagentoProductClient.java:139)
>       at com.niveus.integrator.test.MagentoProductClient.testGetByIdAndSku(MagentoProductClient.java:43)
>       at com.niveus.integrator.test.MagentoProductClient.main(MagentoProductClient.java:151)
>   fail to add media to product